# Set size of icon in DataGridViewImageColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, icons

I am trying to set the size of icons in a column within a datagridview:

```
// .. previous code to fill a dataset with rows of data ...
// Assign dataset into the DataGridView
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = thisDataSet.Tables[0];
// Create icon resource
Icon icon1 = new Icon(SystemIcons.Exclamation, 8, 8);            
// Create a column to hold an icon
DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn(true);
// Set icon for all rows in the column
img.Icon = icon1; 
// Add column to right side of the DataGridView
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
// Move it to the beginning (left side)
this.dataGridView1.Columns[this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1].DisplayIndex = 0;
```

My DataGridView is showing fine with a column on the left with an icon for each row. All icons are of the same size as expected but they look too large to be 8x8 pixels even though I specify my own size. How do I control the icon size?

Comment: Why dont you just use resized image ? :)

Comment: It was my first attempt but for some reason I couldn't make the image display, after searching on the web I found that I can use icons and stayed with that solution cause it worked fairly quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the `Size` passed in the `Icon` constructor is *ignored*, I think you can try using `Image` property instead like this:

```
img.Image = new Bitmap(SystemIcons.Exclamation.ToBitmap(), 8, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks @King King it worked, I had to change my constructor for DataGridViewImageColumn to be DataGridViewImageColumn() so that icons are ignored.

Comment: @LittleFighter there is a property to ignore `Icon` is called `ValuesAreIcons`, just set it to `false` to ignore `Icon` and use `Image` instead.

Comment: @LittleFighter accepting a helpful answer is the best way to say thanks :)

Comment: Ha ha =) sorry pressed the wrong icon +1 when I really meant to press accept! Oh well you deserve both.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the ImageLayout property to Normal.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal
```